# migration from sqllite to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to export table from sqllite and import to postgresql db. but when I try to import into postgresql db it throws some delimiter issue. My table already created in postgresql database. I am following export policy from below link:
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-export-csv/
and got below error when import:

```
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""
```

Any one please help

Comment: Please show the CSV and the complete import statement you're using

Comment: the thing you report as an error doesn't look like an error.  It looks like a fragment of a command.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but i solved it in different way. Maybe this wont fit here but still u would like to try.

1. I first converter/transformed it to .cs file
2. Then I created table in postgresql database with same number of columns and same dtype as it was before
3. Then used i query like following :

`COPY sports(playerid,name,age)       from "<file location>\sports.csv"        DELIMITER ','       CSV HEADER;`

4. Like this all the columns in that table were imported in postgresql.

If this worked for you, your welcome! ;)